# After ordering data, sorting the other variables ascending

Tags: categorical-data

I'm still at a beginning level of R, so I'm having difficulty to make a certain plot called a "lasagna plot". for this I need to first order my data by a categorical value. but after this i have no interest in keeping the data individual bound after that... in short I want the data to be used within the group. maybe the example could clarify a little:

data looks like this, (I attached a image, since I don't know how to attach a datafile):

[image]

Every row is data from one person for ten years straight. I now want to sort them by category VT. After this I want the data for every year ascending. Again: it does not need to stay bound by person (row), only by their VT status.

I already tried these things:

```
data  <- as.matrix(dvt.[,1:10])
data2 <- apply(data,2,function(w) sort(w,na.last=NA))
```

But here it's still irrespective of VT status. Another thing I've tried is using the split function and transforming it back. Very circuitous, I know, but it gave back data as "chr", of which I don't know what it means or how to transform it to integer values.

```
data  <- as.matrix(dvt.[,1:11])
data2 <- split(data, VT)
data3 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(data2), nrow=5))
data4 <- as.matrix(data3[,-11])
data5 <- as.matrix(data4[,1:20])
str(data5)
sorted <- apply(data5, 2, function(w) sort(w, na.last=NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the function in the plyr package

```
# Sort with displacement in descending order
arrange(data, VT, desc(year1))
```

This will sort based on your columns either in ascending or descending order.

Comment: thanks that works. but i need to sort all years ascending within the dvt and pe group, and i just tried to do this using this command but it then messes up the ascending order in the previous year. is there also a way to do that?